# Should I wait for offer letter?

Tags: job-offer

I attended an interview 2 weeks ago. I cleared all the rounds and discussed with HR on salary also. HR told me that he would get back to me in a couple of days regarding my salary and designation and asked me for documents for verification.

I did not get response from HR, hence I called him. He told he'll need another couple of days. When I called two days later, he told that he is waiting for approval and his answer did not change and says same for last few days.

I'm calling HR twice or thrice in week. Should I keep asking him the status of should I just wait without asking. How much time does it take to normally to release offer.

Comment: as a side note - should we get rid of the company name here in the question or is that generally allowed here?

Comment: @imsoconfused Yes, Jan removed it earlier and Vishal added back in another place. I just edited it out again. When people leave in the company specifics, it makes it much easier for the poster to be identified, which has happened here before.

Answer (score 4):

Thrice is the limit of how often you want to call HR in a week, unrequested.  In a busy shop, this person is likely not able to move your particular case along all that quickly.

One technique is to say "when do you think you will have the next step ready?" - in this case, the approval.  The HR person should be able to say "it usually takes X days" and/or "you case is unusual because..." (for example, I had a case where the executive who needed to sign off was trapped in a crazy long off site meeting and couldn't be found for 3 days).  Don't call back until AFTER the date the representative has given to you.

After several days of 'any day now' - start questioning the veracity of this statement.  "Hey, we've been talking every day for the last X days... I'm starting to disbelieve that it's likely to change".

There also comes a point - after about 2 weeks of no progress - where I tend to give up.  This is largely variable based on the market for your skills - if this is the one job offer you're likely to get - keep chasing.  But if you have marketable skills, figure that this company isn't sufficiently mobilized to do hiring and find a position that will actually close the deal.

Also - no offer is real until it's fully approved and handed to you in writing.  Don't stop looking, don't figure that your search is over - but as much effort into interviewing as you do in calling the HR rep.  Worst case scenario on that is you may have TWO job offers - that's a great position for YOU!